# How to implement personal online state function in REST service in Java?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, cordova

I am struggling on a problem about how to present a person's online state with a phonegap project. I have a REST service in the background to indicate and decide whether user state is online or offline, but I do not know if am I doing it the right way, so is there anyone having a better idea/third party/framework to implement this function?

My general idea is as follows:

1. There is an online pool on the server side which is responsible to store the person who has registed online state. The online pool will store user information and user last request time.
2. In client side, every 3 minutes the online user client will send a online request to change the last request time for keeping it in the online pool. And in server side, every 5 minutes the server will run once to check if there is any user request time expired, the user will be removed from online pool and set online state to offline if the request time is expired.

Comment: So what's your question?  And what does it have to do with Java, REST, Java-EE and/or PhoneGap?

Comment: Hi, I want make a application which has a presence function, but I have no idea to make the logic that tell client which one is offline and which one is online in real time, something is like skype online statues.. do you have any idea for the server side, I use rest on the serverside..